# Create mysql polygon column from bounding coordinate columns

Tags: mysql, sql, geospatial

I need to create a column in a mysql database (MySQL 5.5.60-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) that features bounding boxes created from other tables in the database containing the top, bottom, left and right bounding coordinates.

My query looks like this, but can't be executed due to syntax errors. It works fine though when I create a point and just take two coordinates.

```
SELECT 
name.`field_site_sitelong_value` AS name,
basetable.`uuid`,
basetable.`nid`,
msl.`field_elevation_average_value`,
Polygon(
    coordinates.`field_geo_bounding_box_left` coordinates.`field_geo_bounding_box_bottom`,
    coordinates.`field_geo_bounding_box_right` coordinates.`field_geo_bounding_box_bottom`,
    coordinates.`field_geo_bounding_box_right` coordinates.`field_geo_bounding_box_top`,
    coordinates.`field_geo_bounding_box_left` coordinates.`field_geo_bounding_box_top`,
    coordinates.`field_geo_bounding_box_left` coordinates.`field_geo_bounding_box_bottom`
) AS geom

FROM `node` basetable
INNER JOIN `field_data_field_geo_bounding_box` coordinates
ON coordinates.`entity_id` = basetable.`nid`

INNER JOIN `field_data_field_site_sitelong` name
ON name.`entity_id` = basetable.`nid`

LEFT JOIN `field_data_field_elevation_average` msl
ON msl.`entity_id` = basetable.`nid`

WHERE basetable.`status` = 1 AND `field_geo_bounding_box_geo_type` = 'polygon'
```

I assume that the issue has somehow todo with the way I provide the columns to the Polygon().

Comment: try adding another set of parenthesis inside the polygon `Polygon((...))` as stated in docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/gis-polygon-property-functions.html

Comment: Polygon((...)) unfortunately not working  as it only results in "You have an error in your SQL syntax;"

Comment: Every reference I see about Polygon uses it first defined as a String. Maybe that is what is wrong with it... just to check it try this: `GeometryType(concat('Polygon((', coordinates.field_geo_bounding_box_left ......)` get the idea?

Comment: You did a mistake with the concat... I will add one and then you do the rest: `GeometryType(concat('Polygon((', coordinates.field_geo_bounding_box_left, ' ', coordinates.field_geo_bounding_box_bottom , ', ', ......)`

Comment: Glad to know that somewhat worked... now lets wait until someone experienced with Polygon can give some light on it, Besides the query part I have no clue how it works :)

Comment: I'm almost there. If I omit the "GeometryType", I can see that it successfully parsed the values from the columns, I just need to create a blob from that.

Comment: awesome... If you get it to work, don't forget to add an answer for it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the extremely helpful comments of [@Jorge Campos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/460557/jorge-campos) I was able to come up with a working query:

```
SELECT 
name.`field_site_sitelong_value` AS name,
basetable.`uuid`,
basetable.`nid`,
msl.`field_elevation_average_value`,

POLYFROMTEXT(concat(
        'Polygon((', 
            coordinates.`field_geo_bounding_box_left`   , ' ', coordinates.`field_geo_bounding_box_bottom`  , ', ',     
            coordinates.`field_geo_bounding_box_right`  , ' ', coordinates.`field_geo_bounding_box_bottom`  , ', ', 
            coordinates.`field_geo_bounding_box_right`  , ' ', coordinates.`field_geo_bounding_box_top`     , ', ',
            coordinates.`field_geo_bounding_box_left`   , ' ', coordinates.`field_geo_bounding_box_top`     , ', ', 
            coordinates.`field_geo_bounding_box_left`   , ' ', coordinates.`field_geo_bounding_box_bottom`  , 
        '))'
    ))
 AS GEOM

FROM `node` basetable
INNER JOIN `field_data_field_geo_bounding_box` coordinates
ON coordinates.`entity_id` = basetable.`nid`

INNER JOIN `field_data_field_site_sitelong` name
ON name.`entity_id` = basetable.`nid`

LEFT JOIN `field_data_field_elevation_average` msl
ON msl.`entity_id` = basetable.`nid`

WHERE basetable.`status` = 1 
  AND `field_geo_bounding_box_geo_type` = 'polygon'
```

The `POLYFROMTEXT` function turns the complete polygon string from the result of the `concat` function into an actual polygon Spatial Data Type. If you omit the `POLYFROMTEXT` you will get a human readable [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) of each polygon.

Bear in mind that the order of points matter when constructing a WKT for a polygon `(POLYGON((left bottom,right bottom,right top,left top,left bottom)))`, also the first point and the last point need to be identical so that the polygon is closed.